# Spotfire: Change a value to a string and keep other values

Tags: spotfire

I have a column in Spotfire with various values from 0 on up.  Is it possible to create a calculated column where if the value is "0" then it is "Not Complete" and keep the other values?

Tried:
 - If ([daysOpen] = 0, "Not Complete").  **Does not show other values** 
 - If ([daysOpen] = 0, "Not Complete",[daysOpen]). **Error**
 - case WHEN [daysOpen] = 0 then "Not Complete" ELSE [daysOpen] END  **Error**

daysOpen
2
2
2
1
2
1
4
4
3
6
0
0
0
2
3
3
3
3
1
3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot mix data types within a column.

what you can do, however, is something like this:

```
CASE
  WHEN [daysOpen] = 0 THEN "Not Complete" 
  ELSE String([daysOpen]) 
END
```

you can also use an expression like this on a chart axis :)